# How to fix `column "xlog_position" does not exist` error when using AWS DMS for Postgres to Postgres data migration

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-dms

I'm trying to migrate and synchronize a PostgreSQL database using AWS DMS and I'm getting the following error.

```
Last Error Task error notification received from subtask 0, thread 0 [reptask/replicationtask.c:2673] [1020487] 
RetCode: "SQL_ERROR SqlState: 42703 NativeError: 1 
Message: ERROR: column "xlog_position" does not exist; No query has been executed with that handle; RetCode: SQL_ERROR SqlState: 42P01 NativeError: 1 
Message: ERROR: relation "pglogical.replication_set" does not exist; No query has been executed with that handle; RetCode: SQL_ERROR SqlState: 42703 NativeError: 1 Message: ERROR: column "xlog_position" does not exist; No query has been executed with that handle; 
Could not find any supported plugins available on source; Could not resolve default plugin; Could not assign a postgres plugin to use for replication; Failure in setting Postgres CDC agent control structure; Error executing command; Stream component failed at subtask 0, component st_0_JX7ONUUGB4A2AR2VQ4FMEZ7PFU ; Stream component 'st_0_JX7ONUUGB4A2AR2VQ4FMEZ7PFU' terminated [reptask/replicationtask.c:2680] [1020487] Stop Reason FATAL_ERROR Error Level FATAL
```

I'm using two PostgreSQL instances as both source and target. I have already tested and verified that both database instances are accessible by replication instance. Target instance user has full access to the database. Do I need to install any plugins or do additional configurations to get this migration setup working?

Comment: I have the same problem, I followed the configuration setup as described in this link https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Source.PostgreSQL.html#CHAP_Source.PostgreSQL.Prerequisites

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to resolve the issue by following the steps mentioned at 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Source.PostgreSQL.html.

The issue was due to the fact that I was using DMS engine v3.1.4 which required some additional configuration for the replication process to start. These instructions can be found at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Source.PostgreSQL.html#CHAP_Source.PostgreSQL.v10

If you are experiencing this issue double check the DMS replication engine version. This can be viewed under **Replication Instances** in **Resource Management**.

Answer (score 3):

To enable logical decoding for an Amazon RDS for PostgreSQL DB instance

1. The user account requires the `rds_superuser` role to enable logical
   replication. The user account also requires the `rds_replication` role
   to grant permissions to manage logical slots and to stream data using
   logical slots.
2. Set the rds.logical_replication static parameter to 1. As part of
   applying this parameter, we also set the parameters `wal_level`,
   `max_wal_senders`, `max_replication_slots`, and `max_connections`. These
   parameter changes can increase WAL generation, so you should only set
   the `rds.logical_replication` parameter when you are using logical
   slots.
3. Reboot the DB instance for the static `rds.logical_replication`
   parameter to take effect.
4. Create a logical replication slot as explained in the next section.
   This process requires that you specify a decoding plugin. Currently
   we support the test_decoding output plugin that ships with
   PostgreSQL.

The last item can be done with the following command:

```
SELECT * FROM pg_create_logical_replication_slot('test_slot', 'test_decoding');
```

Reference: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_PostgreSQL.html#PostgreSQL.Concepts.General.FeatureSupport.LogicalReplication

Comment: Thanks for taking your time to write this answer. But I'm not using a Amazon RDS instance as the source. My source is a Pg server running on a EC2 instance.